# Ensure Data Integrity Between SFDC and an Mobile Client Device

Tags: rest-api, integration, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

What are the best practices to ensure SFDC REST API communications are transmitted to and from a mobile device with full integrity?

I have a custom iOS app that allows offline editing of Force.com data by field sales reps accessing via 3G-enabled iPads. Everything works well in testing, but field users often complain of sync issues. We can't replicate these issues and think that they are being caused by some sort of data corruption in the communication between the app and SFDC. Maybe the user drives through a tunnel or does something else to momentarily loose their mobile data connection. To safeguard against this, I would like to implement some sort of technique (compression, checksum, ???) which will help ensure that the data have been transmitted without any loss.

Are there any best practices to help ensure integrity between a client and SFDC?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Cameron. Are the sync issues about the mobile users not knowing that the source data has changed before they hit save? Or some other problem?

Comment: I thought the Salesforce Mobile SDK SFRESTApi was graceful in its failure and notifieded the user/reported error in the NSLog. It would make sense to make a global instance an the array of records to be updated and then use the SFRestRequest method to upset. This array will persist as long as the app is running and will be independent of connection issues. When an upset request fails it will notify the user or be captured in the log and can then be debugged for later.

Answer (score 3):

The Internet is based on a protocol suite known as TCP/IP. The Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) is responsible for ensuring that the data is not corrupted and was received in its entirety, in the proper order, through a series of checksums, serial numbers, and acks/nacks that prevent casual corruption due to poor network connectivity, latency, or "flipped bits." Furthermore, most network stacks automatically enable compression for HTTP TCP-based connections as a matter of efficiency on the network. The physical link layer (PHY layer in OSI) also verifies data sends from the next repeating point (e.g. router).

Given that the Internet is essentially impervious to randomly corrupted bits, I would suggest that the problem lies elsewhere. A more probable cause would be a failure to correct catch network errors at the application level rather than any other level in the stack. Generally, this means catching whatever exceptions are thrown and taking appropriate action depending on the error presented through the application programming interface. A pre-maturely severed connection would indicate that the application needs to attempt a retry, for example.

Many novice programmers fail to program defensively against errors, which leads to subtle bugs that may appear in particular circumstances. The best defense against these errors is properly catching, handling, and reporting these errors as they occur, as appropriate. I remember many years ago in my programming class, they first taught us how to read errors, and how to handle errors in code, while later, my programming classes talked only about how to "write" code, and would rarely mention "how to handle errors", even though exceptions are a daily part of a program's lifecycle.

An exception doesn't mean the programmer has done something wrong, it means that "something unusual" has occurred. As such, programmers must handle them correctly because "something unusual" will occur more frequently than not, and the program must be well-equipped to handle that situation so that they can be resolved. Not handling exceptions will lead to data corruption and data loss, and possibly crashes.

Note that none of this is specific to salesforce.com, but more formally generic programming advice. I would state that you can, and should, find a good test suite for whichever language you're using (such as cucumber or JUnit), and write proper tests that include possible failure conditions. By writing unit tests, you can verify that your program will operate correctly in the field.

Answer (score 1):

Cameron,

One simple thing you can do, even just to rule this out (I, like sfdcfox, suspect the sync issue likely lies elsewhere -- probably in determining the cardinality of the sync), is to concatenate and hash selected fields of the object that are sent to / received from the SFDC server. You need to be careful to not hash the entire object, as the variances in timestamps for "last updated" and such will kill the comparison, but a clever algorithm comparing the modified sent fields with the results of a query for the same object... could ensure that your corruption lies elsewhere.

I've discovered over the years that Sync algorithms are often an albatross around the neck of developers. If I may impart some un-asked for advice here: If you're syncing, you're likely to want to do a whole lot of back and forth, and you might want to instantiate some sort of middleware between your mobile clients, and SFDC. A redis box with an api, etc. something to queue actual sfdc interaction. Also, not for nothing, rsync has a fantastic sync algorithm, i commend it to you even though you're not dealing with written files.

Answer (score 0):

Is retrieving updated or created date an option?
To check if it was saved properly I would retrieve it after insert/update.